# How do I print particular JSON value in R?

Tags: r, json

```
install.packages("rjson")

library("rjson")

result <- fromJSON(file="provdata.json.txt")

for (i in seq(1,5,1))

{

  term <- result$data[i]

  print(term)

}
```

[image: [output]]

I was wondering what should I put to only print 13.6 and 4.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not subsetting the list deep enough:
instead of the

```
term <- result$data[i]

print(term)
```

bit, try with

```
print(result$data[[1]][[1]][2])
```

or something similar.